# Remove illumination noise from image to detect april tag

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, apriltags

[image]

In this image,I am trying to detect apriltag, for which I am using lib-dt-apriltags library. As per my knowledge,detection of apriltag is possible when we have clear edges.But because of the illumination / glare / reflection due to light,I am unable to detect it.And I cannot implement heavy computation in my processor.

Is there a way to remove this noise ?
What this problem is referred as so that I can search for document?If you have any sites/related document/links in mind,please do share.

I am about to implement this solution in continuous live feed and camera will be in motion while apriltag comes in frame so it has to be fast.(Also,Lens of the camera was clean when this problem of reflection occured.)

Comment: It looks like *"glare"* to me - normally you would try and diffuse your lighting or view from a different angle.

Comment: The position of apriltag is fixed and the camera is also fixed inside mechanism.The glare can be present at any point on the apriltag in a live feed so changing angle won't help much.I am looking for a solution that can work in any real-time lighting condition.